# click function is not working sometimes in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have done this work to print row-wise data with jquery for that I have made the below code
in this code when I click on print button it is working sometimes print window opens and some times not some times I have to click 2-3 times to open window

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.print').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var newWin = window.open();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '{{route('admin.letter_head.print')}}',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        newWin.document.write(data);
        newWin.document.close();
        newWin.focus();
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="LetterHeadList" class="table dt-table-hover dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="not-mobile">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>title1 update</td>
      <td style="display: flex;">
        <button class="btn mb-2 mr-2 rounded-circle btn-outline-primary print" id="1">print</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>title2</td>
      <td style="display: flex;">
        <button class="btn mb-2 mr-2 rounded-circle btn-outline-primary print" id="2">print</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

can anybody help me in this?

Comment: If you put a console.log call in the function, do you see the console messages?

Comment: @Barmar no there is no console msg in my project it's just because in stack there is some JS missing

Comment: I'm telling you to add it as a debugging step. That way you can see if the function is being called.

Comment: You're claiming that the click function isn't being called sometimes, but I doubt that. This is how we can prove it.

Comment: Perhaps add `type="button" to it` or use `$('.print').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault()` just to be sure it does not try to submit the page

Comment: @mplungjan Why would it submit, there is no form involved.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes wrapping your {{ }} espression because that’s not a literal. It will be processed by your template engine before becoming the real javascript served in the actual response. I wonder how it even worked some times as you said

Comment: @Grumpy perhaps there is? We do not see the complete code. In any case recommended to use type=button if you do not need a submit

Comment: The code would NEVER execute if `url: '{{route('admin.letter_head.print')}}',` did not translate to something like `url: '/print/letter',` or something

Comment: @Mohini You would stop a lot of discussion if you posted the code as seen IN the browser instead of possible server code. If the ajax you show is in an external file, then it also has to be interpreted by the template engine due to the URL route

Comment: @mplungjan They are already buttons, he used the <button> tag, no need  to ad type="button"

Comment: @Grumpy button is default a submit: _type: The default behavior of the button. Possible values are: **submit**: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the **default** if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a <form>, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value._

Comment: @mplungjan Youre right, my bad.

Comment: I can recreate this. It sometimes works, sometimes not https://plungjan.name/SO/printwin/

Comment: I gave an answer but I was shown that my guessing didn't correctly work out so I removed it. Thanks to @mplungjan for his contribution